# pyarmor not working in kali

Tags: kali-linux, python3, pip

I am trying to compile a script with pyarmor but I keep getting the error

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Desktop]
└─$ pyarmor-webui                                                                                     
pyarmor-webui: command not found
```

I installed it using

```
pip3 install pyarmor
```

and trying to run the webui gives the same error

tried this but was not useful

```
python3 -m pyarmor-webui
```

Got this

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pyarmor-webui
```

Comment: typing ``` locate pyarmor  ``` does not show anything

Comment: Try removing the -m parameter; it signifies that pyarmor-webui is a **module** - so you won't find it by searching your $PATH.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick look at `pyarmor`, it does not appear to distribute `pyarmor-webui` scripts.

It does appear that there is a separate package by the same author, try installing that as well: `pip3 install pyarmor-webui`